# Dict Comprehension Index Error

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, dictionary-comprehension

I am currently constructing a dict comprehension from an itertools groupby object, to construct a lookup dictionary for some strings.

```
#groupby iterable arranged by first 3 chars of each element of 'Titles' list.
lookup= groupby(sorted(Titles), key=itemgetter(0,1,2))
#key=concatenate the elements of the tuple, val=list of grouper iterable
lookdict={''.join(i):list(j) for i,j in lookup}
```

This second line gives me `IndexError: string index out of range`. I cannot tell whether it is a problem with `j`, the grouper iterable, or the `join` call in the dict comp.
The following:

```
for i,j in lookup:
    print(''.join(i),j)
```

Is, as expected, not problematic.

It is necessary to have the values as list and the keys as strings to avoid some kind of transformation upon each lookup.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong here?

Comment: copy pasting error, corrected.

Comment: I ran your code and with `Titles = ['123abc', '123456', 'abcdef', 'abc123']` I get `lookdict == {'123': ['123456', '123abc'], 'abc': ['abc123', 'abcdef']}`. Could you post some example data?

Comment: Seems that you have an element with less than 3 characters in Titles list.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a title to `itemgetter` that is shorter than length three, this happens:

```
itemgetter(0, 1, 2)('h')
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The `IndexError` doesn't happen until your comprehension because `lookup` contains `itertools._grouper` objects. These objects are generators that are yet to be unpacked. So, by calling `list` on these objects, you are attempting to unpack them- causing the error.

I think you should change your `key` to be a custom function like:

```
def key(item):
    return item[:3]

key('h')  # --> 'h'
key('hello')  # --> 'hel'
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an interesting question.

You are getting the error because `Titles` contains at least 1 element that is shorter than 3 characters.

Every attemt to consume `lookup` in this case will fail. `for i, j in lookup`, `for i in loopup` and even simply `list(lookup)`:

```
Titles = ['abc', 'asf', 'asf', 'qwer', 'asfgsadfa', 'a']
lookup = groupby(sorted(Titles), key=itemgetter(0, 1, 2))
list(lookup)

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
 print(list(lookup))
IndexError: string index out of range
```